# Swift - UIDatePicker limit the select days

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uidatepicker

I need to prevent the user to select a particular day in `UIDatePicker`. Maybe even remove the Wednesdays of `UIDatePicker`.
Is there any way to make the user can not select Wednesdays?

Comment: It's not exactly the same solution, but something very similar can be found here, which you could tweak to limit the selected day. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398366/uidatepicker-restrict-hours-but-not-date You could select the `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit` and check if it is a Wednesday (4) and handle accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UIPickerView and your own datasource. In datasource you can put any data what you want.
[Good example](https://github.com/rolandleth/LTHMonthYearPickerView).