# How to customize UIDatePicker components?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I am now using default `UIDatePicker` which show only date in my `UIDatePicker` view.The point is, I want to limit my datepicker for showing with range and disable every sunday from that picker cause I am creating auction app.Auction close on sunday,so I need to hide every sunday in my `UIDatePicker`.Also I want to show from unlimited date from past to current date only.

Simple,

1.Setting date range from (unlimited date which was past to current date only)
[....dd/MM/yyyy to...current date only]

2.When I show a datepicker,I dont want to display sunday in that `UIDatePicker`.

Here is what I have in java code

```
Map<String, String> auctionDate = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    SimpleDateFormat sdfDDMMYYYYEEE = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy (EEE)");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDDMMYYYY = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfEEE = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (sdfEEE.format(now).equals("Sun")) {
            now.setTime(now.getTime() + 86400000);
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        auctionDate.put(sdfDDMMYYYY.format(now), sdfDDMMYYYYEEE.format(now));
        now.setTime(now.getTime() + 86400000);
    }
```

Is there anyway I can set this in Swift?Thank you...

Comment: You can create your own `UIPickerView` and set the data source manually, or you could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398366/uidatepicker-restrict-hours-but-not-date). Simply check for `[components day]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create your own `UIPickerView` for doing this. There is no method with which you can remove Sundays from a `UIDatePicker`. What you can do instead is when the user selects a date, check whether its a Sunday. If it is, select the next date by default.