# How to restrict countDownTimer in UIDatePicker?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uidatepicker

Can anyone help me out with this situation?
I have a `UIDatePicker` and I want to restrict it's countDownTimer for one hour.

If it is not possible then what's the way to implement it?
Also, could we restrict the minute wheel to stop its rotation?

Comment: I guess you need a custom UIPickerView. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40969543/224671.

Comment: Just change the date and time format.

Answer (score 0):

After giving some thought, I decided to move on my approach as mentioned below. I just put a label in the centre of my `UIDatePicker` with 00 texts.

[image]

And the output became as follows.

[image]

You now cannot move the minute wheel, only the hour and AM PM Wheel moves.