# Swift datePicker minimum and maximum Hour

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, swift2

Hi all i saw some post of stackoverflow and i figured out how to set a minimum and maximum date. So now in my datePicker you can only select dates after today. Now the problem is that i need to put hour from 8am to 4pm and i can't find anything on internet. How i can do that? Thank you in advance. Here is my code:

```
 @IBAction func datePickerAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
    let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    let now = NSDate()
    datePicker.minimumDate = now
    self.chooseLabel.text = strDate
   save.setObject(strDate, forKey: "ServiceDateChoosed")
    save.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: You can have i look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699910/uidatepicker-setting-minimum-and-maximum-hour

Comment: @PradeepSingh is in objective c :\

Comment: @PradeepSingh i convert it successfully but it only shows an alertView

Comment: thats what you want, if time is exclusive your limit, it gives the error

Comment: okay but if i put 8 AM it gives me error... i think he can't see if it is AM or PM

Comment: according to the link you should write 4PM as 16

Comment: i done that but if i put 8AM it give me error

Comment: oh i found the solution... just put >=

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93976/discussion-between-pradeep-singh-and-marcoc).

Comment: @Marcoc....Could you post an objective c solution for it?